# nesting a link in a div, where that div is surrunded by a link

Tags: jquery, html, css, nested, anchor

Good afternoon,

I'm rebuilding some webpages (using only html/css/jquery/js), and one of them has a series of products on it. Each one is contained in their own div, and repeated over the page multiple times. the products all have an image, some text, and a link.

I'm attempting to change the the product slides so that the entire element is clickable. normally no big thing, as i could just wrap the sucker in an  tag and be done with it.

However, there is a link on the on the product slide. and the CSS theme being used selects based on both class names and element type, so if i change either  the stylings will simply fall off.

I built a rough example of the structure in a codepen: 
http://codepen.io/joshmonks/pen/EyByEr

```
<a class="product-link">
    <div id="product">
        <div><img></img></div>
        <div id="description">text text text</div>
        <a class="inner-link">buy now!</a>
    </div>
</a>
```

I'm wondering the best way to go about handling this situation, I have seen some solutions about using JQuery to listen for the #product div to be clicked, and fire a click event on the link inside. I believe I will be using this solution if no others are found. If possible, I'd like a structural solution over firing events down if possible, as it feels more elegeant for the structure to be like it is in the example, but with valid html

If i could nest a tags, I could simply not put an href on the inner link, and have all the styling applied. then have the href on the outer link, but no styling applied. of course, this is invalid html :(

Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Comment: you cannot do that, a link cannot have a link for a child, it is not coherent. turn your parent a into a div with same class where there is no href attributes

Comment: yes, I'm aware that is illegal html... The problem is that specific styling in the css theme requires looking for anchor tags with specific classes, so 
I can't just remove the "product-link" anchor and add all the classes from that anchor to the "product" div..

Comment: If you're css requires an anchor with a class, and you don't want to change the theme's css files.... The best method is the one you answered yourself. Making the div clickable .

Comment: That's what i was thinking, however I really like Shnibble's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind not having the content selectable inside your element, you could make an overlay that sits over top of the content that is itself an anchor. Position the parent as `position: relative;` and the child `<a>` overlay as `position: absolute; top:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;`.

Just make sure the overlay is a sibling, not a parent, to your `.inner-link` anchor and that it comes before it.

Comment: hmm... I actually really like this idea, one of the big things is that the styling falls apart. The fact this is so easily responsive is a nice + as well,
Going to accept
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a link inside of a link, but you can make a clickable `div` with javascript to wrap the link with, see fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/neya0v76/3/

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="product-link" onclick="goToLink()">
    <div id="product">
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0610/graphics/nospin_1-lg.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div id="description">
        Text Text Text
      </div>
      <a class="inner-link" href="#">buy now!</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function goToLink() {
    window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

However i am looking for structural answers if possible, as the main reason this is an issue is because the CSS theme being used selects based on element type and classes, so changing the outermost anchor to a <div> will cause the styling to fall off.

Could you think of any reason to use this over adding an event listener to the outermost div that fires the anchor's click event?